# Disable BIOS beeping

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, beep-code

I have a Lenovo L480 20LS002YMX which suddenly complains when starting up:

```
0188: Invalid RFID Serialization Information Area.
Press Esc to continue or F1 to enter Setup.
```

According to numerous sites:

```
Message: 0188: Invalid RFID Serialization Information Area.
Solution: The EEPROM checksum is not correct (block # 0 and 1). The system board should be replaced, and the box serial number needs to be reinstalled. Have the computer serviced.
```

(https://www.rsmanuals.com/4369/lenovo-thinkpad-e570-e570c-e575/page-77/)

The laptop still works when pressing **Esc** so I am not thinking of buying a new motherboard.

What annoys me the most is the beeping every time it displays the error. How can I disable that sound? I assume it has something to do with BIOS.

I do not have an option in BIOS to disable the beeping (only to disable Password Beep and Keyboard Beep - they are right now both disabled).

I am BTW running dual boot with Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04

Comment: When I had a similar problem years ago, of course a different board, I simply removed the beeper using wire cutters.  Might be harder on a modern board.

Comment: I already checked for that. Unfortunately, the beeping is coming from the two main speakers which I don't want to dismount

Comment: Did you consider a BIOS update (or at least a "Reset to factory defaults")? This may fix the problem altogether.

Comment: I have updated my BIOS, but there is still no option to disable the beeping

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your keyboard has Sound Off key, you may use it before shutdown,
and it may stay in effect after the boot.
[image]

If the above does not apply to your computer model, then there is
no software solution.

Note that silencing the beeper may also prevent notifications
if other errors arrive.

Comment: There is no beeping when muting the laptop via the mute-key before the shutdown, and booting up again (it stays muted). 
NOTE! It has to be muted and not be on 0.